# All tasks become disabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Every now and then on my Windows 10 machine, maybe once every 3 months, all of my scheduled tasks become disabled and when I realise this I have to open Task Scheduler and manually reenable them. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

@HelpingHand suggested looking for event 142. Here's a screenshot of the last time this happened.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest the first thing to do is to "Enable all task history".  You can then audit when the tasks are disabled to closer pinpoint the time and likley cause.  Once enabled, if you open the Event log: `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx` you can find/filter for EventID 142.  You can enable this auditing from either the Event Log MMC or TaskScheduler MMC snap in..

Comment: You can equally run from an admin prompt: `wevtutil set-log Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /e:true` to enable or change to `/e:false` to disable again.

Comment: At that moment, is there any related Event log occurred in Event Viewer.

Comment: @HelpingHand I've now turned on "Enable all task history". I didn't see EventID 142 anywhere in Event Viewer, so I'll have to wait until the next time it does this.

Comment: @HelpingHand It's been doing it a lot recently, so I decided to revisit my question. Any ideas from the image I just added?

Comment: The event log was really just to provide an audit of when the behaviour is happening to aid diagnose what is causing it.  For example, is it always at the same time? Same relative time from boot. I would suggest installing Sysmon for a while.  https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon  You can install it with `sysmon -accepteula -i`.  The new Event log under: /Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational will hopefully be then useful to correlate what happened the next time you see the event log entries. E.g. a new process being created, who was the parent